# Control where the link leads to from admin in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have coded the website from PSD and integrated it into wordpress.

On the Homepage, there is a Call-to-Action button whose link leads to one of the pages.

My client wants to be able to customize on which page the link points to, and he wants to do this by using the ADMIN PANEL.

Is it possible for me to allow some kind of a new option in the admin area? 
Do you have any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use theme options: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Options